# Reference request: arithmetical implications of an ambient Galois extension

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

**>> Edit 1** Just posted this question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/429822), hoping for more response. **<<**

Let $K\subseteq E\subseteq L$ be algebraic number fields of finite degree over $\mathbb{Q}$, with $L/K$ Galois with group $G$. So $E$ $=$ $L^H$ for some subgroup $H$ of $G$. I am looking for a reference explaining the details of some claims made in the 1980 paper "On the integer ring of the compositum of algebraic number fields" by Toshitaka Kataoka, [this DOI](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0027763000018626), regarding the arithmetic of the ring of integers $\mathfrak{O}_E$ in the context of the Galois extension $L/K$, notably with respect to the ideals $\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma,E}$, which the author refers to as "Elements", described below. (My notation differs slightly from Kataoka's.)

For $\sigma$ $\in$ $G$, let $\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma,E}$ be the ideal of $\mathfrak{O}_L$ generated by the $\alpha-\sigma(\alpha)$ for $\alpha$ $\in$ $\mathfrak{O}_E$. On page 26, bottom, Kataoka tacitly uses the fact that the $\mathfrak{O}_L$-ideal generated by the different $\mathfrak{D}_{E/K}$ equals the product $\prod\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma,E}$ taken over the nontrivial embeddings $\sigma$ of $E$ in $L$ over $K$, that is, the non-trivial ($\sigma$ $\notin$ $H$) representatives of the cosets of $H$ in $G$. With some effort, I managed to see why this is the case (for the proof, see Edit 4 below). Then, p. 30 (top), the author states that if $F$ is another sandwich of $L/K$, with stabilizer subgroup $I$ $\leq$ $G$, then the conductor $\mathfrak{f}$ $=$ $(\mathfrak{O}_E\mathfrak{O}_F:\mathfrak{O}_{EF})$ generates the $\mathfrak{O}_L$-ideal $\prod\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma,L}$ where $\sigma$ runs over $\Sigma$ $=$ $HI-(H\cup I)$, and that this follows from "the fundamental properties of Elements". My questions:

> (1) Shouldn't this be $\prod_{\sigma\in\Sigma}\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma,EF}$? Or does the latter simply coincide with $\prod_{\sigma\in\Sigma}\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma,L}$? (Both of these are false, see Edit 3 below.)

> (2) What is a good reference that describes the general properties of the ideals $\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma}$?

(In the standard algebraic number theory texts, the $\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma}$ figure, at a push, in the definition $T_P$ $=$ $\{\sigma\in G\mid \mathfrak{e}_{\sigma,L}\subseteq P\}$ of the inertia group of an $\mathfrak{O}_L$-prime $P$, but little else is said about these ideals.)

**>> Edit 2 (based on an erroneous assumption, see Edit 3 below)** Regarding the conductor $\mathfrak{f}$ $=$ $(\mathfrak{O}_E\mathfrak{O}_F:\mathfrak{O}_{EF})$, the above result yields that $\mathfrak{f}$ $=$ $\beta\mathfrak{O}_{EF}$ in case $\mathfrak{O}_{EF}$ $=$ $\mathfrak{O}_K[\alpha]$ happens to be monogenic over $\mathfrak{O}_K$, with $\beta$ given by the nice formula:

$\qquad\qquad\beta$ $=$ $(\frac{\prod_{\,\tau\,\in^*\,H/H\cap I}\tau(f)(\alpha)}{g'(\alpha)})^{\mid H\cap I\mid}$

Here, $f$ and $g$ are the minimal polynomials of $\alpha$ over $F$ and $E$, respectively, $g'$ is the derivative of $g$, and $\tau\in^*H/H\cap I$ stands for: $\tau$ runs over a set of representatives of the non-trivial left cosets of $H\cap I$ in $H$. This follows readily from the observation that the elements of $HI-(H\cup I)$ can be uniquely written as $\tau\pi\varphi$ where $\tau\in^*H/H\cap I$, $\pi\in^*I/H\cap I$ and $\varphi\in H\cap I$ $=$ $G_{EF}$. **<<**

**>> Edit 3** Clearly, the conductor of $\mathfrak{O}_{EF}$ in $\mathfrak{O}_E\mathfrak{O}_F$ cannot be an $\mid H\cap I\mid$-th $=$ $[L:EF]$-th power for every $L$ containing $E$ and $F$ and Galois over $K$. Since $\beta$ above was found assuming that $\mathfrak{f} \cdot \mathfrak{O}_{EF}$ $=$ $\prod_{\sigma\in\Sigma}\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma,EF}$, this means that the answer to the first question is **NO**. **<<**

**>> Edit 4** For the interested reader, here are the **proofs**. (Useful references are still very much welcome.)

To see the equality $\mathfrak{D}_{E/K} \cdot \mathfrak{O}_L$ $=$ $\prod_{\sigma\in^{*}G/H}\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma,E}$, where the notation $\in^{*}$ is as in Edit 2 ($\sigma$ runs over representatives of the non-trivial left cosets of $H$ in $G$), let's call the right-hand side $\mathfrak{a}$ and put $h$ $=$ $[E:K]$ $=$ $[G:H]$. As $\mathfrak{D}_{E/K}$ is the $\mathfrak{O}_E$-ideal generated by $(f_K^{\beta})'(\beta)$ $=$ $\prod_{\sigma \in^{*}G/H}(\beta-\sigma(\beta))$ for the $\beta$ $\in$ $\mathfrak{O}_E$ for which $E$ $=$ $K(\beta)$, where $f_K^{\beta}$ is the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $K$, the inclusion $\subseteq$ is clear. If $\mathfrak{P}$ is a prime of $\mathfrak{O}_E$, we can find $\beta$ $\in$ $\mathfrak{O}_E$ with $E$ $=$ $K(\beta)$ for which $\mathfrak{c}$ $:=$ $(\mathfrak{O}_K[\beta]:\mathfrak{O}_E)$ is prime to $\mathfrak{P}$ (Serre, Local Fields, exercise 2 in Ch. III, §6, or, in more detail, Hecke, Algebraische Zahlen, Hilfssatz c on page 135). If $\prod_{\sigma \in^{*}G/H}(\alpha_{\sigma}-\sigma(\alpha_{\sigma}))$ is a typical generator of $\mathfrak{a}$, with the $\alpha_{\sigma}$ in $\mathfrak{O}_E$, then $\eta\cdot(\alpha_{\sigma}-\sigma(\alpha_{\sigma}))$ $=$ $(\eta\alpha_{\sigma}-\sigma(\eta\alpha_{\sigma}))$ $+$ $( \sigma(\eta)-\eta)\sigma(\alpha_{\sigma})$ for all $\eta\in\mathfrak{c}$ and $\sigma \in^{*}G/H$. Since $\eta\alpha_{\sigma}$ and $\eta$ are in $\mathfrak{O}_K[\beta]$, both summands are divisible by $\beta-\sigma(\beta)$ in $\mathfrak{O}_L$, and it follows that $\mathfrak{c}^{h-1}$ $\subseteq$ $\mathfrak{g}$ $:=$ $(\mathfrak{D}_{E/K}\mathfrak{O}_L:_{\mathfrak{O}_L}\mathfrak{a})$. That is, $\mathfrak{g}$ divides $\mathfrak{c}^{h-1}$. As $\mathfrak{c}$ is prime to $\mathfrak{P}$, so is $\mathfrak{g}$. This being true for all $\mathfrak{P}$, we must have $\mathfrak{g}$ $=$ $\mathfrak{O}_L$, so that $\mathfrak{D}_{E/K}\mathfrak{O}_L = \mathfrak{a}$.

Now for the conductor $\mathfrak{f}$ $=$ $(\mathfrak{O}_E\mathfrak{O}_F:\mathfrak{O}_{EF})$. On completion (or away from any given $\mathfrak{P}$, as above), $\mathfrak{O}_F$ $=$ $\mathfrak{O}_K[\gamma]$ for some $\gamma$ $\in$ $\mathfrak{O}_F$. So $\mathfrak{f}$ $=$ $(\mathfrak{O}_E[\gamma]:\mathfrak{O}_{EF})$ $=$ $(f_E^{\gamma})'(\gamma)\cdot\mathfrak{D}_{EF/E}^{-1}$ (Serre, Ch. III, §6, cor. 1). Likewise, we may assume that $\mathfrak{O}_{EF}$ $=$ $\mathfrak{O}_K[\alpha]$ and $\mathfrak{O}_L$ $=$ $\mathfrak{O}_K[\lambda]$. Now we have $(f_E^{\gamma})'(\gamma)$ $=$ $\prod_{\tau \in^{*}H/H\cap I}(\gamma-\tau(\gamma))$, and $(\gamma-\tau(\gamma))\mathfrak{O}_L$ $=$ $\prod_{\pi \in I}(\lambda-\tau\pi(\lambda))\mathfrak{O}_L$ (by the part of the proof of Serre, Ch. IV, §1, prop. 3 that goes through when the subgroup $I$ is not necessarily normal in $G$). Hence $(f_E^{\gamma})'(\gamma)\mathfrak{O}_L$ is the product of the ideals $\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma,L}$ where $\sigma$ $\in$ $\Sigma_1$ $=$ $\{\tau\pi \mid \tau \in^{*}H/H\cap I,\,\pi\in I\}$. By what we have just seen, one has $\mathfrak{D}_{EF/E}\mathfrak{O}_L$ $=$ $\prod_{\tau\in^{*}H/H\cap I}\mathfrak{e}_{\tau,EF}$ $=$ $\prod_{\tau\in^{*}H/H\cap I}(\alpha-\tau(\alpha))\mathfrak{O}_L$ $=$ $\prod_{\tau\in^{*}H/H\cap I}\prod_{\varphi\in H \cap I}(\lambda-\tau\varphi(\lambda))\mathfrak{O}_L$, which is just the product of the $\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma,L}$ taken over the $\sigma$ $\in$ $\Sigma_2$ $=$ $\{\tau\varphi \mid \tau \in^{*}H/H\cap I,\,\varphi\in H \cap I\}$ $=$ $H-I$ $\subseteq$ $\Sigma_1$. Because $\Sigma_1-\Sigma_2$ $=$ $\Sigma$ $:=$ $HI-(H\cup I)$, we conclude that $\mathfrak{f}\cdot\mathfrak{O}_L$ $=$ $\prod_{\sigma\in\Sigma}\mathfrak{e}_{\sigma,L}$, as stated by Kataoka. **<<**

Comment: Just making sure that you know the drill. I agree that it was best to first ask here. But if you don't get any answers here, you may want to ask at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) instead. In a few more days. The question is about a relatively recent research article (IMO 1980 qualifies!), so justifiably it may be at research level. I am not an expert on this stuff, and I also realize that you have a nagging fear that this something a bit more basic. We'll see how it plays out!

Comment: (cont'd) If you decide to post there also, please add links to both versions, so that potential answerers can check the other site also, and won't waste their time unduly only to reproduce something already covered.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: thanks, I will keep that in mind.